# Control Panel not listed in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, control-panel, windows-xp

On my Windows XP SP3 laptop, when I open Windows Explorer, Control Panel is always missing from the folder tree in the left pane, obviously even when My Computer is expanded.

My user account is an administrator, and I can enter the Control Panel by typing it in the address bar of Windows Explorer.

I've searched Google and haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a folder and ho to **Tools** > **Options** > **View** and in the Advanced Settings box, tick **Show Control Panel in My Computer**